# Notepad++ cant modify any file from Samba Share folder

Tags: linux, network-share, samba4

I have created Samba Share in Centos 7.

I usually access the files from the share and modifies in Notepad ++.

Suddenly all files cant be able to save in the same location.

When i tried to save the files. This error is popping up

```
"Please check whether if this file is opened in another program"
```

I am sure the same file was not opened in another program.

I can create files and delete files in the samba share. The only thing is files cant be modified. What might be the cause?

I'm saying again, I'm using Samba Share not the windows share.

Comment: Maybe too simple but have you checked the permissions for the folder(s) on your file system? I suppose the permissions for the share are given correctly. - BTW: sorry I'm not allowed to comment yet.

Comment: i have given chmod 777 permission to the shared folder. I said I can create and delete files in the folder,but not modifying the files

Comment: Av locking the file? Restart your computer and try again

Comment: tried all those simple things

Comment: Use processexplorer and check what process lock the file then.

Comment: already tried that too